# is it possible run a linux command on the output of a previous command ASSUMING that the previous command comes first?

Tags: linux, bash

I know that I can use ``` `` ``` to get the output of a command, for example:

```
echo `ls`
```

but is there a way for me to use the `ls` command first and then run `echo` on it? For example: `ls <some special redirection> echo`? I tried `ls > echo` and it does not do what I want.

The reason I am asking is that sometimes I write complicated commands to get certain output for example: `bjobs -u username01 | grep normal | awk '{print $1}'` is a simple "complicated" command (sometimes they are 6 or 7 changed together). Now, I am currently having to do

```
Mycommand `(complicated string of commands)`
```

but I would much rather just do

```
(complicated string of commands) <some special redirection> Mycommand
```

is this possible?

Comment: If your command needs a command line argument (like `echo`) then no, if it reads from standard input then you already know how to do that (your pipelines are doing that). You could store the output into a variable `out=$(command)` `$(...)` is the same as your backticks only more modern and nest better and then `Mycommand "$out"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use xargs

```
ls | xargs echo
```

Comment: note that `xargs` will strip whitespace and remove newlines. `xargs -0` might be better here. provided there is no null character in the stream. also if output is long might break on maximum argument length. use `xargs --show-limits` to see limit.

Answer (score 0):

When you need more actions on your result, you can parse them:

Parsing `ls` should be avoided, just rewriting the example:

```
ls | while read file; do
   echo I found ${file}
done
```

This construction can be useful for more difficult parsing:

```
echo "red ford 2012
blue mustang 1998" | while read color car year; do
   echo "My ${color} ${car} is from the year ${year}"
done
```